# How to convert a string from iso 8859-1 to utf-8? C# Windows phone 7 -

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, utf-8, iso-8859-1

my question is very simple but at the moment i don't know how to do this. I have a string in ISO-8859-1 format and i need to convert this string to UTF-8. I need to do it in c# on windows phone 7 sdk. How can i do it? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The MSDN page for the [`Encoding class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) lists the recognized encodings.

> 28591 `iso-8859-1` Western European (ISO)

For your question the correct choice is `iso-8859-1` which you can pass to `Encoding.GetEncoding`.

```
var inputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
var text = inputEncoding.GetString(input);
var output = Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes(text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Two clarifications on the previous answers:

There is no `Encoding.GetText` method (unless it was introduced specifically for the WP7 framework). The method should presumably be `Encoding.GetString`.

The `Encoding.GetString` method takes a `byte[]` parameter, not a `string`. All strings in .NET are internally represented as UTF-16; there is no way of having a “string in ISO-8859-1 format”. Thus, you must be careful how you *read* your source (file, network), rather than how you process your string.

For example, to read from a text file encoded in ISO-8859-1, you could use:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

To save to a text file encoded in UTF-8, you could use:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, text, Encoding.UTF8);
```

**Reply** to comment:

Yes. You can use `Encoding.GetString` to decode your byte array (assuming it contains character values for text under a particular encoding) into a `string`, and `Encoding.GetBytes` to convert your `string` back into a byte array (possibly of a different encoding), as demonstrated in the other answers.

The concept of “encoding” relates to how byte sequences (be they a `byte[]` array in memory or the content of a file on disk) are to be interpreted. The `string` class is oblivious to the encoding that the text was read from, or should be saved to.

Comment: so if i read my "string" as a byte array there is a way to convert it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Convert` which works pretty well, especially when you have byte array:

```
var latinString = "Řr"; // år
Encoding latinEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
Encoding utf8Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

byte[] latinBytes = latinEncoding.GetBytes(latinString);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(latinEncoding, utf8Encoding, latinBytes);

var utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```